# Firefox extension to remove " - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia" from page title

Tags: gratis, firefox

When you open a Wikipedia article such [Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple), its title is:

```
Apple - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
```

Is there a Firefox extension to remove the useless `- Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia` part? I understand it is important for branding and SEO, but personally I know what Wikipedia is and I want to unclutter tab names, window titles, names of saved HTML files, headers or articles saved as PDF or printed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The **[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)** Firefox addon would enable you to do that. *Greasemonkey* lets you run "UserScripts" to be run on the page source, in order to modify it.<sup>**1**</sup>

---

<sup><sup>**1:**</sup></sup><sub>Further details can be found at the [Greasemonkey homepage](http://www.greasespot.net/), the corresponding [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), and a collection of scripts at [GreasyFork](https://greasyfork.org/).</sub>

The userscript you'd need would be pretty simple, just running a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) replace on the page's `<title>` attribute. In pseudocode:

```
title = title.replace('^(.*)\s*- .+$','\1')
```

would cut off everything after a dash (including the dash and potential leading whitespaces). [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413439/2533433) could serve as a starting point here. Or, to make it easier for you, just use this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        TitleStrip
// @namespace   IzzySoft
// @description Strips trailing site name from page title
// @include     *
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
document.title = document.title.replace(/^(.*)\s*- .+$/,'$1')
```

Note that you might need to define some exceptions in case some sites uses titles that contain dashes. Picking up your example:

```
Apple - a fruit - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
```

I found no corresponding place to check it against; as my above script uses a "greedy wildcard", it should work as you want it, but I could not verify that.